# Panda Series Delete Rows with Specific Year

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, rows, series

i've researched this and the docs and can't seem to make it work for me. Suppose I have data that looks like this below. It is a pandas series called "y":

```
time
1991-01-01    5.400049
1991-01-02    6.028956
1991-01-03    5.761753
1991-01-04    8.517981
1992-01-05    5.274835
```

I need to delete all rows with specific year such as 1992 shown above. It must be simple but I cannot seem to find the syntax to use. So, i need "y" to look like this:

```
time
1991-01-01    5.400049
1991-01-02    6.028956
1991-01-03    5.761753
1991-01-04    8.517981
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check with

```
#s.index=pd.to_datetime(s.index)
s=s[s.index.year!=1992]
```